# Passing object of base class to function of reference to derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm trying to write code which can find the distance between lots of different types of shapes. I've defined a base class `Shape` with a `virtual distance(Shape& otherShape)` function to find the distance to another shape and then want to define that for all my derived classes.

The problem is that there are lots of possible pairs of shapes, so my solution was to define a set of distance functions outside the classes (circle-circle, circle-square, square-tri etc.) and then call the corresponding one from the distance function. I've added a mini example of what I mean below, with just one derived class `Circle` to demonstrate the problem.

When I try and call my specific `circleCircleDistance` function I get an error because it can't convert the base class into the derived class. Is there any way I can address this or will my design as it stands just not work?

```
enum ShapeType{CIRCLE, SQUARE};

class Shape {
public:
    ShapeType type;
    virtual double distance(Shape& otherShape) = 0;
};

class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    ShapeType type = CIRCLE;
    double distance(Shape& otherShape) override;
};


double circleCircleDistance(Circle& circle1, Circle& cirlce2){
    return 0; //pretend this does the calculation
};

double Circle::distance(Shape &otherShape) {
    switch (otherShape.type){
        case CIRCLE:
            //Here I get the error
            //cannot bind base class object of type Shape to derived class reference Circle& for 2nd argument
            return circleCircleDistance(*this, otherShape);
            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to cast the `Shape&` to a `Circle&`

```
return circleCircleDistance(*this, static_cast<Circle&>(otherShape));
```

As an aside, I'd handle your types a bit differently

```
class Shape {
public:
    virtual ShapeType get_type() const = 0;  // derived classes must override this
    virtual double distance(Shape& otherShape) = 0;
};

class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    ShapeType get_type() const override { return CIRCLE; } // here's your override
    double distance(Shape& otherShape) override;
};

...
{
   switch (otherShape.get_type()){
```

Otherwise you're going to get into a situation where `type` is shadowed from the derived/base classes depending how you access it.

Comment: Oh of course! Thanks, I had tried this but was casting to Circle instead of Circle&! Thanks for the tip on the types too!

Answer (score 1):

Multiple dispatch is not natively supported in C++.
We only have single dispatch thanks to virtual method.

So you can implement [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) for your cases.

An (C++17) "alternative" option is to use `std::variant`, which has [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) which implement multiple dispatch:

You can keep inheritance or drop it.

```
struct Circle {
    Point center;
    float radius;
};

struct Rectangle {
    Point topLeft;
    Point bottomRight
};

using Shape = std::variant<Square, Rectangle>;

double distance(const Square&, const Square&);
double distance(const Square&, const Rectangle&);
double distance(const Rectangle&, const Square&);
double distance(const Rectangle&, const Rectangle&);

double distance(const Shape& shape1, const Shape& shape2)
{
    return std::visit([](const auto& shape1, const auto& shape2){
                           return distance(shape1, shape2);
                      },
                      shape1,
                      shape2);
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks, seems like an interesting idea, I'm going to look into it. One problem I see is having to define A-B and B-A, but I guess once you have one, the other is easy enough just to call the function with the arguments swapped.

Comment: In your tentative as well, you have to handle A-B and B-A. As it is indeed symmetric, one can call the other, but that problematic is unrelated to multiple dispatch anyway.

Comment: Yeah I suppose so, I only need e.g. one circleSquareDistance function, but need to handle the case in both Circle and Square classes with the arguments in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

In c++20 you could use template specialization with concepts for this kind of problem